# The [isn] tag has been deleted

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

**This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. IIf you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.**

---

The [isn](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/isn) tag, which refers to Nicaraguan Sign Language, has currently been applied to just one question, but as it stands, it's not easy to guess what the acronym of the tag means without actually reading its tag wiki excerpt. (`isn` was the abbreviation of "Idioma de Señas de Nicaragua".) The purpose of a tag should be clearly visible and distinguished, which isn't the case with this tag.

To fix this, I have created the [nicaraguan-sign-language](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nicaraguan-sign-language) tag, whose purpose is much more apparent. I've also removed the [isn](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/isn) from the original question, so it'll be deleted automatically within a day.

My primary purpose in posting this was to encourage others (with sufficient rep or moderation ability) to find poorly defined tags like this one, to help improve the classification system set in place for incoming questions.

I also just wanted to let others know that I've made this change, so I can gather feedback on the decision.

Comment: For people reading this later, `isn` was the abbreviation of "Idioma de Señas de Nicaragua". Replacing it with 'nicaraguan-sign-language' makes perfect sense.

Comment: You could also have made isn a synonym of Nicaraguan sign language.